# How to fix: AttributeError: module 'neat' has no attribute 'config'

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, config, attributeerror

I am running through the guide for an AI that plays flappy bird using the NEAT neural network API found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPbHUyVDYDw&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-lwGZWXz5Qgta_YNX3_vLS2&index=7).

When I run his code downloaded from Github, it gives me the error:

```
 "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 438, in <module>
    run(config_path)
  File "test.py", line 412, in run
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
AttributeError: module 'neat' has no attribute 'config'
```

The problem seems to be coming from this block of code:

```
def run(config_file):
    """
    runs the NEAT algorithm to train a neural network to play flappy bird.
    :param config_file: location of config file
    :return: None
    """
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
                         neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
                         config_file)

    # Create the population, which is the top-level object for a NEAT run.
    p = neat.Population(config)

    # Add a stdout reporter to show progress in the terminal.
    p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    p.add_reporter(stats)
    #p.add_reporter(neat.Checkpointer(5))

    # Run for up to 50 generations.
    winner = p.run(eval_genomes, 50)

    # show final stats
    print('\nBest genome:\n{!s}'.format(winner))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Determine path to configuration file. This path manipulation is
    # here so that the script will run successfully regardless of the
    # current working directory.
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, 'config-feedforward.txt')
    run(config_path)
```

However I looked in the Neat documentation found [here](https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module_summaries.html#config.Config) and it says that this attribute does in fact exist. I'm using Pycharm on a mac if that is relevant. Does anyone know where the error coming from?

Comment: What happens if you run `import neat; print(neat.__file__)`?

Comment: What exactly are the imports in this file (before `def run(...)`)? Is there `import neat`, or also `import neat.config`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 As for the first question when I run that in my terminal it gives me "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neat/__init__.py"

Comment: @mkrieger1 for the second question I just have import neat, not import neat.config but I tried neat.config and neat.Config and neither seemed to work

Comment: What happened when you tried to use `import neat.config`?

Comment: @mkrieger1  it would say "packages installed successfully" in Pycharm but then when I run it it returns the error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    import neat.config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'neat.config'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got the same problem on the same system.

Here is how I solved it:

*open PyCharms Preferences,*

*goto "Project: NAME_OF_PROJECT",*

*then open "Project Interpreter",*

*in there uninstall "neat" by clicking the minus button*

*then click the plus button and search for "neat-python" and install that.*

I think PyCharms automatic Interpreter installation method gets something wrong here and installs the wrong "neat" :-P
Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue.
Mine got solved when I ran the same code after installing neat-python instead of just neat through pip.
So try doing this

> pip install neat-python

Also make sure that all the packages given in requirements.txt is already there in your pc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I manually installed the libraries using "import neat", "import graphviz" and other dependencies, but after I used the requirements file the code ran fine. In console , open the folder of the project and type:

pip install -r ./requirements.txt

This solved my error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried that and it just says: "ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './requirements.txt' "

Answer (score 0):

This works on me: Uninstall both libraries 'neat' and 'neat-python' and then reinstall 'neat-python' pip install neat-python, current version 0.92

Comment: Just to let you know that your answer si very similar to the answers that others have left more than a year ago…

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.